# FFmpeg iOS Get UIImage from AVFrame

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg

I am having trouble getting a UIImage out of the frames I am reading into my iOS FFmpeg project. I need to be able to read a frame in, and then convert this to a UIImage in order to display the frame in a UIImageView. My code appears to be reading in the frames, but I am lost as to how to convert them as there is little documentation on how to do this. Can anyone help?

```
while (!finished) {
    if (av_read_frame(_formatContext, &packet) >= 0) {
        if (packet.stream_index == _videoStream) {
            int ret = avcodec_send_packet(_codecContext, &packet);
            if (ret < 0 || ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                printf("av_codec_send_packet error ");
            }
            while (ret >= 0) {
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(_codecContext, _frame);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                    printf("avcodec_receive_frame error ");
                }



                finished = true;
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should know about pixel formats like rgb and yuv. Videos almost always uses yuv formats like yuv420p. Then study AVFrame structure, here some info:

`AVFormat.format` : Current frame's pixel format i.e. `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`
`AVFormat.width`  : Horizontal length of current frame (hence width) unit: pixels
`AVFormat.height` : Vertical length of current frame (hence height) unit: pixels

Now where is the actual frame buffer you might ask, it is in `AVFormat.data[n]`
n can be 0-3. Depending on the format, just first one may contain whole frame or all 4 of them. I.e. yuv420p uses 0, 1, and 2. Their linesizes (aka strides) can be obtained reading corresponding `AVFormat.linesize[n]` value.
As for yuv420p:
`data[0]` is Y plane
`data[1]` is U plane
`data[2]` is V plane
If you multiply `linesize[0]` with `AVFrame.height`, you'll get size of that plane (Y) as number of bytes.

I don't know about UIImage structure (or whatever it is), if it requeris a specific format like RGB, you need to convert your AVFrame to that format using `swscale`.
Here some examples: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/scaling_video.c

In libav (ffmpeg) scaling (resizing) and pixel format conversion are done via same function.

Hope these helps.